# Passing string with single quotes from jenkins to file

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy

In jenkins pipeline I'm defining a condition for where clause in sql statement:

```
else if  (params.targetEnv == "dev"){
    condition = "where DATABASENAME like '%dev%'"}
```

Then I want to replace the condition placeholder in sql file:

```
sh """sed -i 's/@condition@/${condition}/' ${sql_query_file}"""
```

But in the file I get `where DATABASENAME like %dev%` instead `where DATABASENAME like '%dev%'` that means without the single quotes.

Does anybody know how can I pass there the condition with the single quotes?

Comment: Use double quotes around `s/@condition@/${condition}/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

```
sh "sed -i \"s/@condition@/${condition}/\" ${sql_query_file}"
```

[image]

### explanation

1. If you will use a sentence in which there is some variable, you should use double quotes. This is valid on jenkins and unix

```
def condition = "foo"    
echo "$condition"
println "$condition"
```

2. sed sintax need single or double quotes

```
sed -i 's/SEARCH_REGEX/REPLACEMENT/g' INPUTFILE
sed -i "s/SEARCH_REGEX/REPLACEMENT/g" INPUTFILE
```

Double quote should be used if some var is used in the sed argument

3. You should escape the double quote inside of sed because in the parent string there are double quotes

```
echo " foo is \"bar\" "
```

4. Putting it all togeter

```
sh "sed -i \"s/@condition@/${condition}/\" ${sql_query_file}"
```